# How to assign permission to a database user without using database role?

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

I am granting permission on some objects to my user in a database, Is there any way to grant permission to user without using database role?

I can easily do it by creating database role, but I do not want to use role.
I assigned some objects to my user by Database User, in Securables tab, it didn't work!

```
create user [user_test] for login [login_test]
create role role_test authorization user_test
exec sp_addrolemember 'role_test', 'user_test'
grant select on object::dbUser.tbl_05 to role_test
```

I expected I could grant permission to my user and not to use Database Role.

Comment: Yes, just grant the permission to the user. So `GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.YourProc TO YourUser;` instead of `GRANT EXECUTE ON  dbo.YourProc TO YourRole;`. Also `sp_addrolemember` is deprecated, you should really be using `ALTER ROLE ... ADD MEMBER`.

Comment: oh Thanks man, I did it once but I didn't get my resault, I did it again and it works! Thank you so much exacly for telling me that sp_addrolemember is deprecated, I didn't now this! good luck ;)

Comment: I will admit, that even Microsoft haven't stopped using it in their documentation yet though ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#with-grant-option)) and it was deprecated in 2008 if I recall correctly.

Comment: actually I read it in Microsoft documentation an hour ago and I thought the only way is using that! thanks for informing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) 2 options here, you can assign the permission straight to your DB user (as mentioned in the comment) or you can [grant permission on a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-certificate-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which might give you better control in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for your useful response!